# QGIS Python Postcode Search Error

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to create a postcode search using a dialog box but if I press "cancel", it automatically shows ALL of the addresses within the area and doesn't just close the box. Not sure why!

```
def pc_search(self):  
#Get the postcode to search for
qid = QInputDialog()
title = "Enter Postcode"
label = "Postcode:"
mode = QLineEdit.Normal
default = ""

pc, ok = QInputDialog.getText(qid, title, label, mode, default)
print pc

# Open the address data table and search for the postcode
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("ictdsgdev5", "5432", "gistest", "postgres", "gistest1")
uri.setDataSource("public", "OSADDBASE_LEICS", "geom", "POSTCODE like '" + pc.upper() + "%" + "'")
print uri.sql()
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "Address", "postgres")
print vlayer.isValid()

if vlayer.isValid():
    # Add the address layer to the list of layers
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

    # Select the found addresses and zoom to them
    selectList=[]

    for feature in vlayer.getFeatures():
        geom = feature.geometry()
        selectList.append(feature.id())

    vlayer.setSelectedFeatures(selectList)

else:
    #MessageBox displaying no address found 
    QMessageBox.information(None, "Information", "No address(es) found for " + pc.upper())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You display the dialog box and get back the entered values and a boolean indicating if OK was pressed or not

```
pc, ok = QInputDialog.getText(qid, title, label, mode, default)
```

Then you you get the entered value and use it in a `like` query

```
uri.setDataSource("public", "OSADDBASE_LEICS", "geom", "POSTCODE like '" + pc.upper() + "%" + "'")
```

so when `Cancelled` is pressed, `ok` is false and `pc` is empty, resulting in the query `POSTCODE like '%'`, which returns every record.

So, to overcome this, you can apply the query/whole code only if `ok` was pressed. Similarly, if you  don't want to search for all postal code if someone leaves a blank string, you can add the `and pc` in the condition (as a string evaluates to `false` if it is empty)

```
def pc_search(self):  
#Get the postcode to search for
qid = QInputDialog()
title = "Enter Postcode"
label = "Postcode:"
mode = QLineEdit.Normal
default = ""

pc, ok = QInputDialog.getText(qid, title, label, mode, default)
print pc

if ok and pc: 

    # Open the address data table and search for the postcode
    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    uri.setConnection("ictdsgdev5", "5432", "gistest", "postgres", "gistest1")
    uri.setDataSource("public", "OSADDBASE_LEICS", "geom", "POSTCODE like '" + pc.upper() + "%" + "'")
    print uri.sql()
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "Address", "postgres")
    print vlayer.isValid()

    if vlayer.isValid():
        # Add the address layer to the list of layers
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

        # Select the found addresses and zoom to them
        selectList=[]

        for feature in vlayer.getFeatures():
            geom = feature.geometry()
            selectList.append(feature.id())

        vlayer.setSelectedFeatures(selectList)

    else:
        #MessageBox displaying no address found 
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Information", "No address(es) found for " + pc.upper())
```

Comment: Thanks. So I added the "if ok:" and yet it still shows all addresses if i press cancel or OK without filling anything into the text field.

Comment: @Sim I have added the check for empty string. Double check the indentation (ALL code at the same level within the `if` block, including providing enough white spaces in blank lines, beware of tabs)